# Sorting and calculating sum and rank with new columns in R

Tags: r

I have 200 columns and want to calculate mean and rank and then generate columns. Here is an example of data

```html
df<-read.table(text="Q1a    Q2a Q3b Q4c Q5a Q6c Q7b
1   2   4   2   2   0   1
3   2   1   2   2   1   1
4   3   2   1   1   1   1",h=T)
```

I want to sum a, b and c for each row, and then sum them together. Next I want to calculate  the rank for each row. I want to generate the following table:

```html
Q1a Q2a Q3b Q4c Q5a Q6c Q7b a   b   c   Total   Rank
1   2   4   2   2   0   1   5   5   2   12  2
3   2   1   2   2   1   1   7   2   3   12  2
4   3   2   1   1   1   1   8   3   2   13  1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  cbind(sapply(c('a', 'b', 'c'), function(x) rowSums(.[, grep(x, names(.)), drop=FALSE]))) %>%
  mutate(Total = a + b + c, 
         Rank = match(Total, sort(Total, decreasing = T)))
```

**Output is:**

```
  Q1a Q2a Q3b Q4c Q5a Q6c Q7b a b c Total Rank
1   1   2   4   2   2   0   1 5 5 2    12    2
2   3   2   1   2   2   1   1 7 2 3    12    2
3   4   3   2   1   1   1   1 8 3 2    13    1
```

**Sample data:**

```
df <- structure(list(Q1a = c(1L, 3L, 4L), Q2a = c(2L, 2L, 3L), Q3b = c(4L, 
1L, 2L), Q4c = c(2L, 2L, 1L), Q5a = c(2L, 2L, 1L), Q6c = c(0L, 
1L, 1L), Q7b = c(1L, 1L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also go with the `tidyverse` approach. However, it is longer.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
    rownames_to_column(var = "ID") %>%
    gather(question, value, -ID) %>% 
    mutate(type = substr(question, 3,3)) %>% 
    group_by(ID, type) %>% 
    summarise(sumType = sum(value, na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
    as.data.frame() %>%
    spread(type, sumType) %>% 
    mutate(Total = a+b+c, 
           Rank =  match(Total, sort(Total, decreasing = T)))
```

Results:

```
  ID a b c Total Rank
1  1 5 5 2    12    2
2  2 7 2 3    12    2
3  3 8 3 2    13    1
```